# input Field flickering React MDbootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I Was trying to create a login form. But while focusing the input field the whole page flickers. Below is the render code,

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-8 login-image"/>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="login-form">
                        <h2 className="mb-5">Form login</h2>
                        <form>
                            <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">Sign in</p>
                            <Input label="Email"
                                   icon="envelope-open" group type="email"
                                   validate error="wrong"
                                   success="right"/>
                            <Input label="Password" icon="lock" group
                                    type="password" validate/>
                            <div className="text-center">
                                <Button>Login</Button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**CSS Code**

```
 .login-image {
background: url("../../resources/coming-soon2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

}

```
.login-form {
min-height: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
padding: 50px;
```

}

I am getting the below output as expected but onFocus of the`textfield` the whole webpage starts to flicker. It is happening only on chrome
[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzudB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did You try to add also onBlur event? I've copied Your code, add onBlur event and it's working correct, without flickering.